# How to search on columns with mRender

Tags: javascript, datatables

I have a datatable with server side pagination. I have one of the field set to turn into a hyperlink. When I type in the filter box, it won't include results from that column. Here's my DT initialization.

```
$("#EPLogTable").dataTable({
    "serverSide" : true,
    "processing" : true,
    "ajax" : "serverSideProcessingAllLogs.php",
    "aoColumns" : [
        {"sName" : "Date"},
        {"sTitle" : "App Name"},
        {"sTitle" : "Page Name"},
        {"sTitle" : "AppName"},

        {"mData" : null, "mRender" : function(data, type, full){
            if(data[4] != null){
                return "<a href='userGraph.php?uid="+data[4]+"'>"+data[4]+"</a>";
            }else{
                return "";
            }


        }}
    ]
});
```

Is there a way to be able to filter by that column?

Comment: is it perfectly work before the search keyword input?

Comment: If you enable server-side processing ( bServerSide ) then you are telling DataTables that the server side script will do all the sorting and filtering... http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/18528/search-sorting-not-working-when-using-aocolumns

Comment: @lv0gun9 correct. I am aware that the server side is handling filtering. However, if I take out the "mRender" part, I am fully able to search on that column.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#EPLogTable").dataTable({
    "serverSide" : true,
    "processing" : true,
    "ajax" : "serverSideProcessingAllLogs.php",
    "aoColumns" : [
        {"bSearchable": false }, // 
        {"sName" : "Date"},
        {"sTitle" : "App Name"},
        {"sTitle" : "Page Name"},
        {"sTitle" : "AppName"},

        {"mData" : null, "mRender" : function(data, type, full){
            if(data[4] != null){
                return "<a href='userGraph.php?uid="+data[4]+"'>"+data[4]+"</a>";
            }else{
                return "";
            }


        }}
    ]
});
```

read this :)
http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/columns
'bSearchable'

Comment: Well, copying in the code you posted didn't change it's behavior. I still can't search on the last column. I'll type in something that I know is in there but it won't show those results. If I comment out the mRender portion, it works.

Comment: Oh, I missed this before. It's also giving an error "undefined is not a function"